# Curve fitting a sum of Gaussian's to 6 peaks

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I was wondering if anyone could show me a way of fitting multiple gaussian curves to a data set containing 6 peaks(data comes from a diffraction pattern from a copper gold alloy crystal). the way i have at the moment involves using multiple gaussian equations added together meaning i have to give multiple guesses of values when curve fitting.

Comment: Try searching google for "nonlinear curve fitting python"

Comment: You can a fit a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) to your data, but keep in mind it won't necessarily find a fit you expect to. See sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture

Comment: You might find lmfit useful. See https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-3-fitting-multiple-peaks-and-using-prefixes for example that fits 2 Gaussians and an exponential decay.  It should be easy to extend to more Gaussians.

Comment: Checked it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used a genetic algorithm to search error space and find initial parameter estimates for scipy's Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear solver.  The most recent versions of scipy now include the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm which is what I had been using.  It will take a bit of experimenting on a previously fit data set to tune things like population size or genetic crossover strategy, but then you should have a way for the computer to find initial parameter estimates in this way.  It takes a while to run, so let it go overnight, but it can be automated.